# Unable to run script with particular user

Tags: linux, authentication

I have a requiremnt to execute a particular script(say script1) only with a specif user(say XYZ).
So, I have created the user and I am able to execute script1 using xyz.

Inside script1, I am running another script(say script2) background.

Problem is that the script2 is not executed using the user XYZ.
However using any other user I am able to execute script2.

I don't understand, Does the newly created user need any special permission for this?

Could someone please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It was based on the commands you are trying to execute, some of the commands needs some special permission to execute. If you share the script will be easier to answer

Comment: Sorry I cannot share the actual script. In deed I try a script with just echo statements and even that is not working. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Make a group (exp : test) and set group owner of script 2 with test and excute permission to user and group:

```
#chown :test script2
#chmod 754 script2
```

then for script1 set user owner and group owner to XYZ user and just excute permission to user:

```
#chown XYZ:XYZ script1
#chmod 744 script1
```

then add XYZ user to test group

```
#usermod -a -G test XYZ
```

just XYZ user can excute script1 and every one in test group can excute script2